# Spark coalesce looses file when program is aborted

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

in Scala/Spark i am using a DataFrame and write it into a single file using:

```
val dataFrame = rdd.toDF()
dataFrame.coalesce(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(filePath)
```

This works fine. But I figured out using the console and Hadoop's `ls` command, that while it is coalesced, the file and folder is not on the Hadoop file system.

When you type `hadoop fs -ls hdfs://path`, there is no such file or directory. After the `coalesce` is done, the path is again there and also the file which was coalesced.

This might happen because the coalesce needs to delete the file and create a new one?!

Here the problem is now: When i kill the process/app while the file is not on the file system, the complete file is deleted. So an failure of the system would destroy the file.

Do you have an idea how to prevent the file loss? I thought Spark/Hadoop would care of this.

Thanks, Alex

Comment: zero323, what you suggested is what I would suggest, should spark do internally when i call "coalesce". I am confused why spark does not behave like this. I already implemented your suggested solution but thought i could reduce coding and complexity by simply using coalesce.

Comment: `coalesce` doesn't remove anything. It wouldn't even touch your data if not for a subsequent write. Data is removed by writing. Now there are two aspects of the problem. The main reason to overwrite is to reclaim disk space.  In case like this behavior you expect is is not desired.  From a more general point of view application should never be design in a way when writing data can cause permanent data loss. If even if write succeeds there is no guarantee that data won't be corrupted or there is no mistake in your pipeline.

Comment: Finally Spark provides HA options so situation when you loose progress due to single machine failure can be avoided.

Comment: Hi zero323, thanks for you explanation. So it seems that there is no other solution than to store the files first, then aggregate it and afterwards copy it and delete the old files.

Comment: Why store first then aggregate? Or coalesce for that matter? Unless you ensure HA the rest is kind of true although I am not sure how it is problem in practice unless you overwrite a file which is used in the previous steps. And that shouldn't happen at all.

Comment: In my case i am doing batch-streaming from kafka. In each batch I am processing 10.000 messages. Spark creates .part files for each batch run. So you get a 50mb block file only containing 1mb of messages. As you can imagine, after some time you will have a lot of wasted quota. So I tried to use coalesce to aggregate the existing and the new messages into one and overwrite the existing file. So there would be only one file which is growing. But this concept seems not to be good. I described it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346660/spark-batch-streaming-of-kafka-into-single-file

Comment: It looks more like a job for a database. If not I would write data, make sure it hasn't been corrupted and only after that remove old one.

Comment: Yes, so I decided to coalesce the data and write it into an a new folder and file. The old .part files will then be later on deleted using a job.